# How to tell Kotlin that star projections represent the same type parameter

Tags: generics, kotlin

I ran into the following problem:
Let's assume we have `class A<T>` and `class B<T>` and we can get `A<*>` and `B<*>` from somewhere, for example, we have read-only interface like this:

```
interface ABProvider {
    fun provideA(): A<*>
    fun provideB(): B<*>
}
```

Then, we know by some internal logic that this provider always returns `A's` and `B's` with the same type parameter under the star-projections. More formally, we know that exists some `T` such that `provideA()` returns `A<T>` and `provideB()` returns `B<T>` at the same time.

And then we want to be able to do things like this:

```
fun <T> doSomething(a: A<T>, b: B<T>) {...}

val a = provider.provideA()
val b = provider.provideB()
doSomething(a, b) // <- here is the problem
```

So is there a way to solve that? I tried to do something like this:

```
fun <T> cast(a: A<T>, b: B<*>) = a to (b as B<T>)
```

but it doesn't work, it says "Cannot infer type parameter T".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a generic type T in the interface itself and return only value of type A<T> and B<T> from them? Can you explain what's the usecase to we can help you further!

Comment: @AnimeshSahu as I mentioned in a question, we have read-only access to the interface, so we can't change it. The usecase is quite the same as the described one: I use some library in my code, I can get `A<*>` and `B<*>` from some class in this library, and I can pass `A<T>` and `B<T>` to some function in this library, in addition, there is some logic that implies equality of type parameter (but I don't know why this class was designed this way).

Comment: What you can do is `doSomething(a as A<Any>, b as B<Any>)` or use `Any?` because Any is supertype of anything, and hence in-variance will work.

Comment: But that will make their wildcard not wildcard anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fun <T> doSomething(a: A<T>, b: B<*>) {
  val bc = b as B<T>
  // Do things with a and bc
}
```